# Programmatically Add libraries to the gradle file in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, android-activity, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, android-library

Is there any way to add dependencies programmatically to gradle file.

I mean, i want to add a dependency/library to gradle from an activity.

Comment: You can't do it with an Activity, but what is the sense of this request?

Comment: I am creating an aar file and then using the same in other application.  I need the dependencies that are used while generating aar file, to be reflected in the application.  That is not happening by just adding aar file.

Comment: and then? Which is the requirement? To add the dependencies of the aar file?

Comment: Exactly... But i gone through so many links, they are stating to manually add the dependencies, that r used in aar, to the application gradle file... That should not be the case...

Comment: Check the answer below. It explain why you need to add the dependencies and 2 ways to achieve it.

Answer (score 1):

You can't add the dependencies in an Activity since Gradle uses the `build.gradle` to build the project. You could try to write a custom plugin but I am not sure that it is the right way.

Reading your comments in the answer your request is to add the dependencies used by the aar file.

The **aar** file **doesn't contain the nested (or [transitive](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Transitive_Dependencies)) dependencies** and doesn't have a pom file which describes the dependencies used by the library.

It means that, if you are importing a aar file using a `flatDir` repo you have to specify the dependencies also in your project.

The solution is to use a **maven repository** (you have to publish the library in a private or public maven repo).
In this case, you will not have the same issue because of gradle downloads the dependencies using the pom file which will contain the dependencies list.

**To publish** a library in Central Maven or JCenter, it is very long to explain in an answer. Hovewer you can read these posts:

- Publish on [JCenter](http://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/how-to-upload-library-to-jcenter-maven-central-as-dependency/en)
- Publish on [Central Maven](http://gmariotti.blogspot.it/2013/09/publish-aar-file-to-maven-central-with.html). Another blog for [Central Maven](http://chris.banes.me/2013/08/27/pushing-aars-to-maven-central/)

An alternative is to add the module as "external module".
Inside a project, you can refer **an external module**.

Just use:

```
Project
|__build.gradle
|__settings.gradle
|__app (application module)
   |__build.gradle
```

In `settings.gradle`:

```
include ':app' 
include ':myExternalLib'
project(':myExternalLib').projectDir=new   File('pathLibrary')
```

In `app/build.gradle`:

```
dependencies {
    compile project(':myExternalLib')
}
```

Pay attention to `myExternalLib`.
You have to use the path of the library inside the other project, **not the root** of the project.